Conceptual explanation for failure of Kazhdan's property (T) for most rank 1 groups
Note that this is a repost from MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/473178/conceptual-explanation-for-failure-of-kazhdans-property-t-for-most-rank-1-gro
Kazhdan himself proved in his 1967 paper (where he introduced property (T)) that simple Lie groups $G$ of real rank $\textrm{rk}_{\mathbf{R}}(G) \geq 2$ have the property (T).  This fact can be proven by different methods, e.g. (like in Bekka-de la Harpe-Valette) by proving the corresponding fact for $\textrm{SL}_3$ and $\textrm{Sp}_4$ and reducing the general case to these groups, or alternatively, by proving a relative property (T) for the pair $(\textrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R}) \ltimes \mathbf{R}^2, \mathbf{R}^2)$ and reducing the general case similarly.
I am also familiar that the complementary series $(\pi_{\lambda})_{-1 < \lambda < 0}$ show that $\textrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$ does not have property (T). I am wondering whether there is a conceptual reason (along the lines of rank 1 groups have insufficient directions) why property (T) cannot be proven for rank $1$ like in higher rank, and how to formalize this conceptual reason. I know that this is a very imprecise question, and I would be really happy with any intuitions.
Thank you very much in advance!

I do not understand the question (in fact, you do not have one, as far as I can tell, there is no single sentence which ends with the question mark). Are you asking why a particular proof of property (T) fails in rank 1? If so, which one? Or maybe you are asking why several proofs fail in rank 1? In this case, you should also specify which proofs you have in mind. Or maybe you are asking why two out of 3 families of rank 1 groups do not have Property (T)? I think, it will be a wasted bounty, unless you come up with a precise question.

I just think there has to be a deeper reason why property (T) does not hold in rank 1 generally. I am unsatisfied with just saying "the proofs don't go through because you can't fit a semidirect product into rank 1 groups". I would also be satisfied with an answer to the question  of the form "I also thought about this and here's why you should not expect a deeper, more conceptual reason".
